# after using unset ($_POST['nome']), the $_POST doesn't get the form input

Tags: php, forms, post

i want to unset the $_POST superglobal so it doesn't have any value before the user submit the form. I used the unset($_POST['name']),and it doesn't update with the form input after that. 
i've tested without unseting the $_POST and it  work just right. I've also tried to use $_POST = 'something' but the form didn't replaced the value also.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>to-do-list</title>
    <!-importanto css->
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    ?>

    <!--formulario com ação post--> 
    <form action="" method="post">
        <h1> To Do List </h1>
        <table class="table">

            <tr>
                <?php
                    unset ($_POST['nome']);
                ?>

                <td><input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="nome" ></input></td>
                <td><button>enviar</button></td>


            </tr>   

            <?php


                //definindo a variavel que vai capturar o input do usuário->    
                $name=($_POST['nome']);


                //definindo a query que será passada ao mySQL
                $query = "insert into itens (item) values ('{$name}')";

                //definindo qual banco de dados deve ser acessado   
                $conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'to-do-list');

                //verifica se existe algo no $_POST, se tiver, mostra na tela e envia ao servidor.



                if (isset($_POST['nome'])) {
                  mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
                }
                else {

                }           


                //busca as tarefas listadas no banco e transforma em um array   
                function listaTarefas($conexao) {

                $tarefas = array();
                $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from 
                        itens");


                //loop para colocar as tarefas antigas dentro do array $tarefas 
                while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
                array_push($tarefas, $item);
                }

                return $tarefas;    
                }   

                //para cada item do array tarefas, imprime o valor da coluna "item" na tabela
                $tarefas = listaTarefas($conexao);
                foreach($tarefas as $item) :
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?= $item['item'] ?></td>
                <td>        
            </tr>

            <?php
                endforeach
            ?>


        </table>

    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: You don't need to do this. The variable doesn't have anything in it unless they submit the form.

Comment: right, but if the user doesn't write something on the input field and press the button anyway, it will send an empty string to my SQL bank, and i don't want it.

Comment: Your question says "before the user submits the form". That's not the same as the user submitting the form without filling in the input field.

Comment: Your code unsets the variable unconditionally. So even when the user fills in the field and submits the form, you remove it before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

All of your PHP code runs before the page is sent to the user.  All of your PHP code runs again when the user submits a form.

For a "postback" where the same URL / page both creates a form and processes it, you need to split up your code on the page.

```
$show_form = true;
$errors = false;
$error_list = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    ... code to validate and process the form ...
    ... if success, render the results page set $show_form = false ....
}

if ($show_form)
{
   ... render the form page, including $error_list if validation failed
}
```

Also, this line is very dangerous -- google "SQL injection" and "Little Bobby Tables"`

```
$query = "insert into itens (item) values ('{$name}')";
```